# Rails Postgresql JSONB column check if key value was changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

Given I have `data_config` as jsonb column

I want to check the value of specific **key** if was changed before saving.

**Test Data:**

```
data_config: {
  "status"=>true,
  "text"=>"sample"
}
```

**Rails Model:**

```
 attr_json_config(default_container_attribute: :data_config)
 attr_json :status, :boolean, default: true

 before_save :check_config

 def check_config
   if self.status_changed? # => want to have something like this to check if value changed?
      # ... do something
   end
 end
```

This **works** in my case, but I believe there's a better way.

```
status_val = self.attr_json_changes.changes_to_save.try(:[], "status")
# above returns [true, false] (old & new value)

if status_val.try(:first) != status_val.try(:last)
  ...do something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you compare the params with the current value?

Because you give very little information, I'll assume you want to change other key in jsonb if the status changed. In this case, you should make your record immutable before the updated value is ready to commit.

So in your controller, it should be like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if params[:data_config][:status] != @model.['data_config']['status'] # check if value change
      # ... do something
      new_params = do_something
    end

    if @model.update(new_params)
      # render success
    else
      # render failed
    end
  end
end
```

I hope this approach can help you.

Comment: Hi @KSD thanks for your answer, but I need to put my condition in dirty callback